# Ruby on Rails Route simplification of views folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

I am having a hard time understanding routes in rails. I have a folder with a bunch of portfolio pages. Each is in .html.erb format and I have made a get route for each one.

How can I simplify this?

```
Location: app>views

portfolio/uniquename1.html.erb
portfolio/rexpage.html.erb
portfolio/armstrong.html.erb
portfolio/occupy.html.erb
portfolio/fancythat.html.erb
```

etc...

Routes look as follows:

```
NewPortfolio::Application.routes.draw do

get "portfolio/uniquename1"
get "portfolio/rexpage"
get "portfolio/armstrong" 
get "portfolio/occupy" 
get "portfolio/fancythat" 

etc...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :portfolio do
  collection do
    get 'occupy'
    get 'armstrong'
    ...
  end
end
```

Static pages are a little awkward in Rails. You should try to minimize them. [Here's a RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages/) which deals with a few different solutions.